# Angular material 10: Error retrieving icon :mysvg! User login is required

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can't really repro this issue as I use authn/authz in my project.

The issue is with this custom SVG. here's the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class IconService {
  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  public registerIcons(): void {
    this.loadIcons(Object.values(AppLanguage), "../assets/flags");
  }

  private loadIcons(iconKeys: string[], iconUrl: string): void {
    console.log(iconUrl);
    iconKeys.forEach((key) => {
      const keyLower = key.toLowerCase();
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        keyLower,
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          `${iconUrl}/${keyLower}.svg`
        )
      );
    });
  }
}
```

When user is logged in to the app I see the SVG, no problem. But when user is not authenticated I get the following error:

> Error retrieving icon :mysvg! User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint
> at SafeSubscriber._error (icon.js:713)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
> at SafeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:135)
> at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
> at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
> at TakeSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
> at TakeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
> at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
> at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
> at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:56)

But I do NOT restrict any access for assets!
This is the routes setup:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "someroute",
    canActivate: [TmvAuthorizedGuard],
    canLoad: [TmvAuthorizedGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./concerts/concerts.module").then((m) => m.ConcertsModule),
  },
  { path: "unauthorized", component: NotAuthorizedComponent },
  {
    path: "**",
    component: NonExistingPageComponent,
  },
];
```

The SVG icon is used in HomeComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem turns out that the using a full url instead of the relative path to assets did the trick. It should work as your solutions.

instead of :
"../assets/flags";

use :
BASE_URL + "/assets/flags";

Where BASE_URL is your dynamically retrieved url (e.g. localhost:4200).

Not entirely sure why this happens I think its related to the error handler from Angular material. Error is in both Angular 9/10.

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor seems bugged. Probably because backend and frontend are in the same app registration in azure.

The if statement ( marked with HERE ), is checking if the request URL starts with http. this should cover angular material SVG loaded icons and any other assets. Just import the custom interceptor instead.

Work around was to just not use the interceptor and modify it a bit.

```
@Injectable()
export class MsalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private auth: MsalService ,  private broadcastService: BroadcastService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // HERE
        if(!req.url.startsWith("http")){
            return next.handle(req);
        }

        const scopes = this.auth.getScopesForEndpoint(req.url);
        this.auth.getLogger().verbose("Url: " + req.url + " maps to scopes: " + scopes);
        // If there are no scopes set for this request, do nothing.
        if (!scopes) {
            return next.handle(req);
        }

        let token: string;

        // Acquire a token for this request, and attach as proper auth header.
        return from(
            this.auth.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes })
                .then((response: AuthResponse) => {
                    token = response.tokenType === ServerHashParamKeys.ID_TOKEN ? response.idToken.rawIdToken : response.accessToken;
                    const authHeader = `Bearer ${token}`;
                    return req.clone({
                        setHeaders: {
                            Authorization: authHeader,
                        }
                    });
                })
        )
        .pipe(
            mergeMap(nextReq => next.handle(nextReq)),
            tap(
                event => {}, // tslint:disable-line
                err => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
                        this.auth.clearCacheForScope(token);
                        this.broadcastService.broadcast("msal:notAuthorized", err.message);
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```